# Store Latitude and Longitude and display in a Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm currently working on an application, i have this button which link to some server codings and i will get back a latitude and longitude which is shown in LogCat. My only problem is how to store this latitude and longitude and display it in a map?

Comment: Can you take the trouble of reading basic documentation about `MapView`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

```
public GeoPoint where(double lat, double lng) {
    GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
    return p;
}
```

and then call the method to move the map with:

```
mapController.animateTo(where(52.123456, 0.123456));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have this lat and lng, but how do i pass in to the map to show the location according to what i have pass in?

Comment: @sowhat if by 'display' on map you mean put a marker at that spot then there are thousands of tutorials for that spread over the internet, Google it...but if you just want to go to that point then this answer does exactly that, it animatesTo() the coordinates you give it.